# Javascript pause sound doesn't work when switch is off

Tags: javascript, jquery, audio

in a simple web application made with jQuery Mobile im using Howler.js Javascript for audio, the page has a flipswitch widget:

https://theredlips.digitalking.it/giochi/Sx1.html

When i switch to SI the music start to play in loop but when i switch to NO it doesn't pause.

I use the pause() method that is provided with Howler.js

Here is the part of the js code:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/howler/2.0.3/howler.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).on('pagecreate','[data-role=page]',function() {
// console.log('PAGECREATE');
$('#flip-select-audio').change(function() {
      var sound = new Howl({
      src: ['Sounds/Sx1.mp3', 'Sounds/Sx1.ogg','Sounds/Sx1.m4a'],
      loop: true,
    });
    if ($(this).val() == "on") {
        sound.play();
    } else {
        sound.pause();
    }
});
});
</script>
```

and the part of the HTML code:

```
<form>
    <label for="flip-select-audio"><strong>MUSICA:</strong></label>
    <select id="flip-select-audio" name="flip-select-audio" data-role="flipswitch" data-mini="true">
        <option value="off">NO</option>
        <option value="on">SI</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

Thanks in advice for any help.

Comment: What **exactly** do you mean by "*it doesn't pause*"?

Comment: the sound continue playing in background, you can check it, in my question there is the link to the page where i have the code.

Comment: Though it's not likely to help - remove comma (`,`) after `loop` property.

Comment: done it but unfortunately didn't solved

Comment: I put an alert inside else and the alert will display when i switch to NO so the code is ok, it seems the problem is the sound.pause() that doesn't work properly, i also tried sound.stop() but still no luck.

Answer (score 0):

Not a bug, i moved var sound = new Howl external to change function of the flipswitch widget and now works correctly!